# heat indicator light goes off and ac switches off after some time

Tags: heat, indicators, electronic-control-module

I have Hyundai EON. Wwhen I start the car, the heat indicator works fine, but after 20-30 kms, the AC suddenly switches off and the heat indicator light also goes off. What would be the reason?

We raised issue at the Hyundai car service center, but after 5 attempts they are still not sure, but they are saying some problem with ECM. Is this the reason?

Comment: Did they attempt to diagnose the issue by trying to duplicate driving conditions when it happens? It sounds they just checked with the car in the bay.